# Copy HTML code or image link from a webpage using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am searching for some JavaScript that does the following:

This is the html code from where I want to extract the image url

```html
<img id="icImg" class="img img500" itemprop="image" src="http://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/6w8AAOSwQgpW~oRP/s-l500.jpg" onload="picTimer=new Date().getTime();" clk="0" alt="Leather-Jacket-Men-Sheep-Skin-Limited-Edition-Bomber-Slim-fit-Jacket-Stylish-36" mskuskip="false">
```

Now my aim is to copy that `http://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/6w8AAOSwQgpW~oRP/s-l500.jpg` to a variable

How can I do it using JavaScript only?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you're looking for

```
var url = document.getElementById("icImg").getAttribute("src");
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this it will work :**

**jQuery :**

```
var url = $("#icImg").attr("src");
```

**Javascript :**

```
var url = document.getElementById("icImg").getAttribute("src");
```

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/zfc66L46/

Comment: "Use Downvotes and Comments Strategically" ? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-reputation-fast-on-any-stack-exchange-site

(upvoted you, just for it)